# Find all function such that $f(f(x+y))=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all continuous function over real numbers such that $f(f(x+y))=f(x)+f(y)$

We have $$f(f(x+y))=f(x)+f(y)\tag{1}$$Also $$f(f(x+y))=f(x+y)+c \tag{2}$$ where $c$ is $f(0)$.From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have, $$f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)+c$$ the solution to this function equation can be found as $f(x)=kx-(x-1)c$. Here $k$ is $f(1)$ Now putting this the original functional equation, $$f(f(x+y))=(k^2-2kc+c^2)(x+y)-c(c-k-1) \tag{3}$$ $$f(x)+f(y)=(k-c)(x+y)+2c \tag{4}$$ For problem condition $(3)$ and $(4)$ must be equal ie $$(k-c)(k-c-1)(x+y)-c(c+1-k)=0$$ which implies$(k-c)(k-c-1)=0$ and $c(c-k+1)=0$. The solution to these equations are (0,0) ,and all number of the form (u+1,u) for all real u. Thus we conclude that the functions satisfying this functional equation are $f(x)=x,f(x)=c,f(x)=x+c$ where c is a real constant.

My question: Is my proof correct? If yes, am I just overdoing it?

**Edit 1**

*2 comments and 1 answer later I have not received answer to my original question. Is my proof correct?*

Comment: Note that $f(f(x+y))=f(x+y)+c$ already implies that $f(z)=z+c$ at least when $z$ is in the image of $f$.  If you can prove that $f$ is surjective then you are done.  And writing $f(x)=kx-(x-1)c$ already shows that $f$ is either surjective or constant.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098231/determine-all-functions-fx-such-that-ffxy-fxfy?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm... In fact, you can set $g(x)=f(x)+c$ which leads the F.E. to $g(x)+g(y)=g(x+y)$. So using the continuous hint, you can use the Cauchy function to $g$, so we get $g(x)=kx$. So you can say that $f(x)=kx-c$. Putting this to the original F.E., we get $k(k(x+y)-c)-c=k(x+y)-2c$, so $(k^2-k)(x+y)=(k-1)c$. $k^2-k$ and $(k-1)c$ should be $0$, so it leads to $(k, c)=(1, c), (0, 0)$.

Comment: Wait $kx+c$ is true only for $k=1$

Comment: @Has Oh, that's right. I'll fix it. Actually, we can see that the function $f$ works of $k=c=0$. I'll fix it correctly again.